# not like does not apply to string extracted from dropdown menu

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code should be able to return me some records that doesn't included the following:

```
 RequestStatus <> 'Submission'
 OR RequestStatus <>'Pre-CRC submission'
 OR RequestStatus <>'CCT Review'
```

Each of the items listed above are menu items coming from a drop down menu.Which should n't be listed in the final results. However, these items are listed in the results. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

```
Select   

    RequestStatus,
    IncidentID,
    max(LastModifiedDateTimeJ) as 'newfield',
    OwnedByTeamJ,
    DetailsJ,
    Status,
    OwnedByTeam
    from IncidentTicket
where 
    CAST(CreatedDateTime as  DATE) >='05-01-2019'
    AND JournalTypeName like '%Journal - Note%'
    And OwnedByTeamJ like '%C - OS Review%'
    AND
       (
        RequestStatus <> 'Submission'
        OR RequestStatus <>'Pre-CRC submission'
        OR RequestStatus <>'CCT Review'
       )

group by  RequestStatus,IncidentID,OwnedByTeamJ
,DetailsJ,Status, OwnedByTeam
```

Thanks,

Comment: You need `AND` (not `OR`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    where RequestStatus not in ('Submission','Pre-CRC submission','CCT Review')
```

The ORs were messing you up

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
RequestStatus <> 'Submission'
OR RequestStatus <>'Pre-CRC submission'
OR RequestStatus <>'CCT Review'
```

will **always** be true. You probably meant to use:

```
RequestStatus <> 'Submission'
AND RequestStatus <>'Pre-CRC submission'
AND RequestStatus <>'CCT Review'
```

*can* actually be true if the value is unlike all of the given values.